# Copying similar files from geodatabases into single geodatabase using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I'm trying to copy files form multiple geodatabses into a single database. I'm looking for two subclasses. Here's the code so far, it isolates the feature classes but when I try to run the search cursor it only runs it on the last feature class that the arcpy.da.Walk throws out. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

```
import arcpy, os, string, sys
workspace = r"C:\Users\A\Desktop\A"
outWorkspace = "C:\Users\A\Desktop\A"
arcpy.env.workspace= workspace


for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass"):
    for filename in filenames:
       arcpy.env.workspace=filename
       desc = arcpy.Describe(dirpath)
       featureTest=(os.path.join(dirpath,filename))
       print filename

fc= filename
fields = ["F_CODE"]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print (row)
```

Comment: Move your cursor up underneath, and indented to print filename. Then it will run for each feature class. How do you know when you find the two feature classes? is it by name?

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I'm trying to figure out a way to select two of the different "F_CODE" from the list that is created and then copy them. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying you've got two different fields that are like F_CODE or that you only want to values of F_CODE to be copied?

Comment: The values of F_CODE

Comment: Use arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer with a where_clause. How are you copying them? If you can list the two F_CODE values I'll put that in as an answer.

Comment: The two values are 220 and 113. I was thinking about using append or InsertCursor to copy them unless theres an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

What you've got so far is a good first step. From there I would use [MakeFeatureLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000) and [Copy Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000035000000) / [Append](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000050000000):

```
import arcpy, os, string, sys
workspace = r"C:\Users\A\Desktop\A"
outWorkspace = r"C:\Users\A\Desktop\A" # this is the same as the input workspace, that's bound to cause problems
arcpy.env.workspace= workspace

QueryFilter = "F_CODE in (220,113)"

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass"):
    for filename in filenames:
        # arcpy.env.workspace=filename # not necessary
        # desc = arcpy.Describe(dirpath) # what are you trying to do here?
        featureTest = os.path.join(dirpath,filename)
        print filename # this is very close to filenames which is already in use
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(featureTest,"Layer",QueryFilter)

        # I'm assuming you want to copy to the output 
        # location using the same name, if that's not right
        # then comment that out and set earlier
        OutFC = os.path.join(outWorkspace,filename) 

        if arcpy.Exists(OutFC):
            # if the feature class exists then add to it
            arcpy.Append_management("Layer",OutFC,"NO_TEST")
        else:
            # if the feature class doesn't already exist then create it
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("Layer",OutFC)

            # clean up the layer name so it can be used again
        arcpy.Delete_management("Layer") # remove the layer - not the features it points to
```

These tools avoid having to use search and insert then copy geometries/values... a little tedious.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an error though. line 2227, in CopyFeatures. raise e. arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output Failed to execute (CopyFeatures). Any thoughts?

Comment: There's something wrong with your output location, perhaps it doesn't exist (check the name and path). Ensure you have write access to that location.

Comment: Its copying now but seems to not be filtering anything out and copying everything.

Comment: Is it copying all feature codes an not just the two that are wanted? Test the query filter in ArcMap using select by attributes and change if needed. Ensure that the QueryFilter is specified on the make feature layer and that it's the layer that's copied/appended and not the feature class. Also ensure that the previous iteration is removed prior to running this script.

Comment: Correct, its copying all feature codes. I have the QueryFilter on and checked on ArcMap and can select them with these attributes.

Comment: And it is the layer that is copied/appended, the output doesn't already exist and the output isn't the same as the input? Strange.. Are you running this in ArcMap, ArcCatalog or on command line?